# Progress dialog during tab switch

Tags: java, android

When the user switches from tab A to tab B it takes a long time (6 seconds), so I put in a progress dialog to let the user know that the app is working on it.  The timeline is as follows:

1. Activity B onCreate - creates ProgressDialog and puts long tasks in a background Thread.
2. Activity B onStart
3. Activity B onResume
4. Activity B appears on the screen

This all works great with one "minor" snafu- the app intermittently crashes because the onResume function references something that is created by the background Thread.  It is, in other words, a classic race condition.

To fix the race condition I did a "join" on the thread right before the reference in onResume, but that makes the progress dialog not show up until the background thread is done (i.e. it shows up for a split second and then goes away) and the app acts like it is hung while the background thread is working.  Apparently the progress dialog cannot show up until onResume completes.

My question is this: how can I get the ProgressDialog to show up without crashing the program?  Or do I need to either get the offending reference out of onResume or live with the app acting hung?

Comment: Removing the reference looks like the natural solution.  I haven't read the details of `onStart` and `onResume`, but I guess they were meant to run very quickly and not have to wait for a lengthy computation in another thread to finish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a kludgey solution wherein the onResume function waits for the intermediate result that it needs, but not for the entire background thread to finish.  This is ugly, I know, but it appears to work.

The better long term solution, I believe, is to separate the creation of the needed object from the long initialization steps that it does when it is created.  The timeline would then be:

1. onCreate
2. Create object
3. Create progress dialog
4. Create background thread, have it do long initialization of object.
5. onStart
6. onResume (with no check/sleep loop).

Answer (score -1):

Are you using Threading as provided by the Java platform or are you using the Android convenience classes?

I am referring to `AsyncTask`. More than likely you are running in to issues with your Runnables posting at inconvenient times. The `AsyncTask` class packages up these features nicely. Subclass `AsyncTask`, specifying the types for your params, progress, and result. Then hide your dialog in the `onPostExecute` method, while you perform background work in the `doInBackground` method.

Sample code:

```
AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> parseTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // Dismiss the progress dialog
        dismissDialog(PROGRESS_DIALOG);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Do background work                
        return null;
        }
};

// Start the background thread
parseTask.execute();
```

Taken from a live code base. Also don't feel too bad, concurrent programming is easily one of the more difficult systems to program. It is promising that you were able to recognize and identify the race condition.

Comment: I am using the "Thread" class, which I believe is provided by the Java platform.  What Android convenience classes are you referring to?

Comment: I don't understand how using AsyncTask would solve the problem of guaranteeing to finish before onResume and still showing the progress dialog.  Can it do that?

Comment: Simply using AsyncTask won't solve your problem, but moving the race condition code to the `onPostExecute` function will ensure it does not run until the data loaded by the background thread is valid.

Answer (score -1):

A dirty solution would be to have one ProgressDialog for steps 1 and 2, and then create a second identical-looking one for steps 3 and 4.

Comment: Does that mean that a progress dialog created in any of the onCreate/Start/Resume functions appears while that function is running and then disappears when it exits?  Why would it disappear?

Comment: No, what I'm saying is, you'll avoid the race condition if you dismiss the dialog before it happens, then create a new one that onResume can reference without problems. I guess what I'm saying is get rid of the offending reference.

Comment: That's why it's a "dirty" solution. Better than having nothing on screen IMO.